# java.lang.RuntimeException with custom checkbox

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I set OnCheckedChangeListener for  3 checkboxs which defined on custom layout , when i run app  , its crashes with logcat error and force close .

any help will be highly appreciated ,

my code as bellow :

**Splash.java**

```
 public class Splash extends Activity{  
 MediaPlayer ourSong;
 CheckBox checkbox_first ;
 CheckBox checkbox_second ;
 CheckBox checkbox_third ;  
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.splash);  

  checkbox_first = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_first);
  checkbox_first.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);

  checkbox_second = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_second);
  checkbox_second.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);

  checkbox_third = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_third);
  checkbox_third.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);   
 }
private OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {

if(isChecked){
switch(arg0.getId())
  {
    case R.id.checkbox_first:
         if (checkbox_first.isChecked()) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
        startActivity(intent);  
        }
        else{    
                 checkbox_second.setChecked(false);
                 checkbox_third.setChecked(false);
         break;
            }     
    case R.id.checkbox_second:
         if (checkbox_second.isChecked()) {

            setContentView(R.layout.splash);  
            Thread timer = new Thread()
           {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    sleep(2000); 
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
                finally
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
                    startActivity(intent);  
                 }
              }                          
            };
           timer.start(); 
           }           
else{   
        checkbox_third.setChecked(false);
        checkbox_first.setChecked(false);
         break;
      }              
   case R.id.checkbox_third:

         if (checkbox_third.isChecked()) {        
           ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashsound); 
           ourSong.start();
        final Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(2000); 
                    }
                  catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                    }
                  finally{
                  Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
                        startActivity(intent); 
                            }
            }}; 

                   timer.start(); 
                        }                      
 else{  
        checkbox_second.setChecked(false);
        checkbox_first.setChecked(false);
      break;}
  }
}

}
};
@Override
protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSong.release();
    finish();
          } 
       }
```

**Prefs.java**

```
  public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity{    
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {

MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);

getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {

if (name .equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) {
try {
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);

new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
public void run() {

((TextView) view).setTextSize(25);  
((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.RED); 
} 
}
);                                        
return view;
}
 catch (InflateException e) {        
 }
  catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {          
  }
}                                  
return null; 
}
}
);           
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);                                    
}   
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.aboutUs:
        Intent i = new Intent("com.test.demo.ABOUT");
        startActivity(i);
    break;
    case R.id.preferences:
        Intent p = new Intent("com.test.demo.PREFS");
        startActivity(p);
    break;
    case R.id.exit:
        finish();
    break;
}
return false;
  }
  }
```

**xml folder : prefs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
     <Preference 
       android:layout="@layout/checkbox_layout"
       android:key="splash" />
     </PreferenceScreen>
```

**checkbox_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >   

<CheckBox 
  android:id="@+id/checkbox_first" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:textColor="#B22222" 
  android:textSize="25sp" 
  android:text="First" 
  android:onClick="onCheckBoxClicked"
  />       
<CheckBox 
  android:id="@+id/checkbox_second" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:textColor="#B22222" 
  android:textSize="25sp" 
  android:onClick="onCheckBoxClicked"
  android:text="Second" 
  />       
<CheckBox 
  android:id="@+id/checkbox_third" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:textColor="#B22222"       
  android:textSize="25sp" 
  android:onClick="onCheckBoxClicked"
  android:text="Third" 
 />       
</LinearLayout>
```

**splash.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/splash" />
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
  ComponentInfo{com.test.demo/com.test.demo.Splash}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.test.demo.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:26)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

LINE 26 indicated to :

```
   checkbox_first.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
```

Comment: here `setContentView(R.layout.splash);` you are setting `splash` layout for `Splash` Activity but CheckBox is inside `checkbox_layout` layout

Comment: is your `splash.xml` same as `checkbox_layout.xml` because you initialize check boxes and you have `R.layout.splash`. Suspect initialization fails bcoz of this.

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K thanks for comment my master , i know that but i cant solve it i, itry to set it to pref class but i cant intiate intent of splash to openn mainactivity , im not expret please help me , it will act like sharedpreference effect as user will check any checkbox and when he start app again it start as per his preference checked either with spalsh or without splash or with splash and music (this is my goal) , thanks again

Comment: @Raghunandan my dear sir thanks for your comment , i update splash .xml to my post , both are different , how we can solve it , thanks again

Comment: @Raghunandan i have option menu which must rise pref when click it must open pref activity which has the 3 checkboxs , im not expert any advice please sir.

Comment: @androidqq6 you can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity. So you need to have checkboxes in splash.xml or `setContentView(R.layout.checkbox_layout)`;

Comment: @Raghunandan my dear the cenario of app like this : app star with splash for aperiod of time then go to main activity which had option menu , one item of option menu is pref which clicked open pref activity which has 3 checkboxs as per user preference he/she check any box which determine how the app will start  next time either :1- wihout splash ( directly open main activity ),2- open splash screen without music for period of time then go to mainactivity , 3- open app with splash and music then go to main activity , thanks

Comment: @androidqq6 dear i am sorry i cannot help you further. wait for some expert advice.